# Почему компилятор gcc не находит функцию Py_Initialize?

Tags: c

есть код на C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello!')");
  Py_Finalize();
}
```

При компиляции программы командой:

```
gcc -o first_test.exe first_test.c -I C:\Python39\include -L C:\Python39\libs -l python39
```

Лезут следующие ворнинги:

> In file included from C:\Python39\include/Python.h:85, from
> first_test.c:2: C:\Python39\include/pytime.h:123:59: warning: 'struct
> timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of
> this definition or declaration   123 | PyAPI_FUNC(int)
> _PyTime_FromTimeval(_PyTime_t *tp, struct timeval *tv);
> |                                                           ^~~~~~~ C:\Python39\include/pytime.h:130:
>
> 12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not
> be visible outside of this definition or declaration   130 |
> struct timeval *tv,
> |            ^~~~~~~ C:\Python39\include/pytime.h:135:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be
> visible outside of this definition or declaration   135 |     struct
> timeval *tv,

И следующие ошибки:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> C:\Users\grett\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjh99I1.o:first_test.c:(.text+0xf):
> undefined reference to _imp__Py_Initialize'
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> C:\Users\grett\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjh99I1.o:first_test.c:(.text+0x25):
> undefined reference to _imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> C:\Users\grett\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjh99I1.o:first_test.c:(.text+0x2c):
> undefined reference to _imp__Py_Finalize collect2.exe: error: ld
> returned 1 exit status

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой!

Comment: Gcc находит, линковщик дллки найти не может. `-L C:\Python39` пробовал?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731100/link-to-python-with-mingw

Comment: -L C:\Python39, а какой файл подключать?

Comment: Ссылка на похожую проблему возможно смогла бы помочь, но я на windows

Comment: Может [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/466181/) сможете найти ответ

Comment: Там инструкция для linux, у меня windows стоит

Comment: Проблема оказалась в раности разрядностей python и mingw, после установки mingw 64bit все встало на свои места, так как python был 64-битный